# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar en Python por versiones?

Tags: python, lista, ordenamiento

Tengo una lista de cadenas que contienen números de capítulos de series.
La lista la tengo en este formato:

```
Serie2- (1)
Serie2- (4)
Serie2- (10)
Serie2- (3)
```

Al realizar `lista.sort()` se quedarían así:

```
Serie2- (1)
Serie2- (10)
Serie2- (3)
Serie2- (4)
```

¿Existe manera de hacer que se ordenen por versiones?

```
Serie2- (1)
Serie2- (3)
Serie2- (4)
Serie2- (10)
```

¿O tendré que cambiar los nombres uno por uno y añadir 0 a los números de una sola cifra ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `LooseVersion`, que permite ordenar "por versiones" en lugar de numéricamente:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

versiones = ["Serie2- (1)", "Serie2- (4)", "Serie2- (10)", "Serie2- (3)"]
lv = [LooseVersion(ver) for ver in versiones]
lv.sort()
```

Ahora el orden es el bonito, en base a versiones:

```
>>> lv
[LooseVersion ('Serie2- (1)'),
 LooseVersion ('Serie2- (3)'),
 LooseVersion ('Serie2- (4)'),
 LooseVersion ('Serie2- (10)')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno para tu caso podrias usar el metodo `sort` pero adecuandolo a lo que necesitas, te doy un ejemplo:

Primeramente te dejo el enlace a la documentación de `sort` [Ordenar COMO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) de la página de *python.org* ya que allí encontrarás ejemplos de **ordenamientos complejos**.

Ahora explico un poco el como podrias resolverlo:

```
re.findall(r'\d+', cad.split("-")[1])[0]
```

Lo que hace el código anterior es devolverme los números de una cadena en este caso de `" (1)"`, `" (4)"`, etc. ya que hago un **split** para partirlo por `"-"`, me devolvera `1`, `4`, 'etc'.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre `re` en [éste enlace](https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html)

Ahora utilizaremos el metodo sort para ordenarlo utilizando **lambda** *(En el primer enlace encontraras información sobre ésto)*:

```
series.sort(key=lambda cad: (int)(re.findall(r'\d+', cad.split("-")[1])[0]))
```

Lo que se hace con el código anterior es ordenar tu lista por los números que se encuentran despues del guión de cada cadena.

Ahora un ejemplo con los datos que pusiste:

```
import re
series = ["Serie2- (1)", "Serie2- (4)", "Serie2- (10)", "Serie2- (3)"]
series.sort(key=lambda cad: (int)(re.findall(r'\d+', cad.split("-")[1])[0]))
print (series)
```

Salida:

> ['Serie2- (1)', 'Serie2- (3)', 'Serie2- (4)', 'Serie2- (10)']

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Una aproximación sencilla sería "capturar" los números de versión y ordenar numéricamente por los mismos. Podemos usar expresiones regulares para extraer cualquier número entre los parentesis

```
import re

regex = r"\((\d+)\)"

versiones_ordenadas = sorted(versiones, key=lambda x: int(re.search(regex, x).group(1)))
print(versiones_ordenadas)

['Serie2- (1)', 'Serie2- (3)', 'Serie2- (4)', 'Serie2- (10)']
```

Con `key=lambda x: int(re.search(regex, x).group(1))`, establecemos una función anónima para retornar el valor por el cual vamos a ordenar, en este caso es el valor numérico de la expresión capturada.